# how can i modify the appearance of google places autocomplete or just access the json directly and do it all myself?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Google Maps/Places 'autocomplete' API be used via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803521/can-google-maps-places-autocomplete-api-be-used-via-ajax)

There seems to be disagreement about whether or not this is even possible. I grabbed the url that its using from console but it is totally un-editable, changing the callback causes an error.

Example: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?1sgoo&4sen-US&5sUS&9sestablishment&callback=*xdc*._y53chi&token=28177](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?1sgoo&4sen-US&5sUS&9sestablishment&callback=_xdc_._y53chi&token=28177)

That works (at time of posting) but changing anything causes it to break. If I could control the callback or let jQuery modify the callback for use with jsonp I'd be set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to access the Google Maps Autocomplete API.

The first is via the [`google.maps.places.Autocomplete`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Autocomplete) class. This provides all the necessary implementation in Javascript. However, you have complete control over styling. Use the `pac-container` and `pac-item` CSS classes.

The second is via the [Autocomplete Web Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html). This is not accessible via the browser because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (there is no JSONP API). This is the most flexible way to access Autocomplete results.