# JavaScript - How to get the city name suggestions from Google Auto-completion API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

As you may know, you can have [**suggestions from Google places API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) for city names.
By default you have to create an auto complete object with this code :

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

And the suggestions will be shown for the specified element, which is `input` here . But I want to get all of the suggestions and display them somewhere else. How can I do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doesn't seem like there's an easy way, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726317/1633510) for how to intercept the JSONP